# Split a string in java using balanced parantheses

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I need to split the following string 
((OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' OR OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' OR (OPERATING_CARRIER='VA'    AND (FLIGHT_NO=604 OR FLIGHT_NO=603))))
to :

```
OPERATING_CARRIER='AB'
OPERATING_CARRIER='AB'
OPERATING_CARRIER='VA'
FLIGHT_NO=604
FLIGHT_NO=603
```

I have tried the following piece of code

```
String syntax = "(OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' OR OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' OR     (OPERATING_CARRIER='VA' AND (FLIGHT_NO=604 OR FLIGHT_NO=603)))";
List < String > matchList = new ArrayList < String > ();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]*)\\)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(syntax);
while (regexMatcher.find()) 
{
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

I am getting an output of OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' OR OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' OR (OPERATING_CARRIER='VA' AND (FLIGHT_NO=604 OR FLIGHT_NO=603

Comment: Any Other methods of doing can can also be suggested

Comment: Maybe you could get rid of all parentheses and split by OR and AND

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
String s="((OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' OR OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' OR (OPERATING_CARRIER='VA' AND (FLIGHT_NO=604 OR FLIGHT_NO=603))))";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s*=\\s*(?:'[^']+'|\\d+)").matcher(s);

while(m.find()) {
    String aMatch = m.group();
    // add aMatch to match list...
    System.out.println(aMatch);
}
```

#### Output

```
OPERATING_CARRIER='AB'
OPERATING_CARRIER='AB'
OPERATING_CARRIER='VA'
FLIGHT_NO=604
FLIGHT_NO=603
```

#### Regex

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Nice visualization. Is there a tool or site for that?

Comment: @Stephan I am posting the code i have used: Hi Folks I have used the following code for splitting the string

    `String input= "name = 'name_1' AND in_stock IN {'in_stock_1','in_stock_2'} AND ( price BETWEEN '01-jan-2015' and '31-may-2015' OR price = 'price_3' )";
    
    
    String sa =input;
           String[] arr = sa.replaceAll("[()]+","").split("\\s*(\\sOR|\\sAND)\\s*");
           for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
           {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
       }`
thanks for all the inputs and help

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way (maybe not the more efficient)

1. remove brackets
2. split on `OR`
3. split on `AND`

And here is an implementation

```
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    String input = "((OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' OR OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' OR (OPERATING_CARRIER='VA' AND (FLIGHT_NO=604 OR FLIGHT_NO=603))))";
    String withoutBrakets = input.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)","");
    String[] withoutOr = withoutBrakets.split("OR");
    for(String sOr : withoutOr) {
        String[] withoutAnd = sOr.split("AND");
        for(String sAnd : withoutAnd) {
            results.add(sAnd);
        }
    }
```

Output

```
[OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' ,  OPERATING_CARRIER='AB' ,  OPERATING_CARRIER='VA' ,  FLIGHT_NO=604 ,  FLIGHT_NO=603]
```

**EDIT** Regexp from @Stephan's answer looks definitely better

Answer (score 1):

Hi Folks I have used the following code for splitting the string

```
String input = "name = 'name_1' AND in_stock IN {'in_stock_1','in_stock_2'} AND ( price BETWEEN '01-jan-2015' and '31-may-2015' OR price = 'price_3' )"; 
String sa =input;
String[] arr = sa.replaceAll("[()]+","").split("\\s*(\\sOR|\\sAND)\\s*");

for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
   System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

thanks for all the inputs and help